# Regex in find command. Simple search using alternation doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex, tcsh, file-find

I think I'm fairly well-versed in regex in tcl, but in the shell, I'm very new. It seems the syntax is slightly different.

I'm simply trying to recursively find all files that have **multib** or **multi_b** in the name.

```
find . -type f -regex ".*multi(b|_b).*"
```

does not work. Even getting rid of '**|_b**' in the expression doesn't find a match. It seems I have to escape parentheses in order to group, opposite of how it's done in tcl.

```
find . -type f -regex ".*multi\(b\).*"
```

matches. However, if I add the OR character, I get no matches.

```
    find . -type f -regex ".*multi\(b|_b\).*"
```

No match. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: You need to enable `ERE` (extended regex mode) or other advanced regex modes in `find` command.

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you. Why isn't advanced regex the default?

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's suggestion was the problem. Using **-regextype egrep** worked. I wonder why that mode isn't the default, though.

Comment: The usual answer to any "why isn't advanced whatever the default" question for any given tool is backward compatibility so a new release of a tool with "advanced whatever" support doesn't break scripts that existed before "advanced whatever" came along but I don't know the history of this one to say for sure if that's the answer in this specific case.